npx expo start is giving error related to node js version
I am following the basic tutorial here:
https://docs.expo.dev/router/installation/
I have node version v20.16.0 installed as verified with node -v too. when I am running
npx expo start
I am getting error pasted below. does anyone know what is wrong?
Starting project at C:\Users<user>\cod\rn\my-app
Starting Metro Bundler
Error: Node.js version 17 is not supported. Please upgrade to Node.js 20 or newer.
Error: Node.js version 17 is not supported. Please upgrade to Node.js 20 or newer.
    at _assertNodeFetchSupport (C:\Users\mysau\cod\rn\my-app\node_modules@expo\server\src\assertion.ts:19:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mysau\cod\rn\my-app\node_modules@expo\server\src\assertion.ts:33:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mysau\cod\rn\my-app\node_modules@expo\server\src\environment.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)

I was trying to start the expo development server.

It's possible that you have a PATH variable set for Node.js version 17 which might be causing the issue.
Along the same line, try removing all traces of the older Node.js version and rebuild and see if it works.

I have checked in user and system variables, there are no PATH variable set to node.js version 17 and I do not have any version of node other than 20. I also tried completely uninstalling node and nvm and reinstalled but still it is showing same error.
